# max and min return current time when used to find max and min dates

Tags: javascript, date, google-sheets, max

UPD
I am trying to find the maximum and minimum dates in my Google Sheets document.
Apps Script is used to achieve this task.
I tried to use this code:

```
function maxMinDates() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var funnelData = SS.getSheetByName('Funnel data'); 
  var datesRange = funnelData.getActiveRange();
  
  //Something is wrong with this line of code
  var datesValues = new Date(datesRange.getDisplayValues());

  var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null,datesValues));
  var minDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null,datesValues));

  //Write result into cells
  var maxDateCell = SS.getSheetByName('Pivot').getRange('I11').setValue(maxDate);
  var minDateCell = SS.getSheetByName('Pivot').getRange('I12').setValue(minDate);

  console.log(maxDate);
  console.log(minDate);
```

Thank you, All, for the replies below.
So, I tried to use "new Data()" but I get "invalid date" now in the console. I have tried different formatting in my sheet but no luck.

UPD
Ok. I have tried to rewrite the code and it moved a bit further in terms of correctness. But now I understand that I call to ARRAY like object incorrectly. Any thoughts on the following version of the code, please? The Error I get now is:
"TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object"
in the last two lines starting with "apply" statement

```
function maxMinDates() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
   var datesValues = SS.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValues();
     console.log(datesValues);

     var datesValuesDateFormated = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(datesValues), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
     console.log(datesValuesDateFormated);

  var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null,datesValuesDateFormated));
  var minDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null,datesValuesDateFormated));
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please notice that Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages. Next time please tag accordingly. Thank you :)

Comment: `Date(...)` should be `new Date(...)`, too lazy to find a dupe.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, thank you for the input, however, my intent was to state javascript instead of java but it seems like I missed the moment when auto-selection switched my choice to java.

Comment: What does `console.log(datesRange.getDisplayValues())` show? That is - what exactly is trying to be turned into a Date when you do `var datesValues = new Date(datesRange.getDisplayValues());`

Comment: `datesRange.getDisplayValues()` feels like it is not a single date thus `new Date(datesRange.getDisplayValues())` for it would not be valid - instead loop through those perhaps if it is an array of dates?

Comment: In your situation, I think that when the date value in the cell is the date object, this can be used. But from your question, I cannot know about it. So, can I ask you about the detailed type of the date value in the cell? By the way, `getDisplayValues()` returns a 2-dimensional array. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you. I have tried formatting the source cells to be both text and date formatted. Nothing helped. However, I think used an array object incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand the type of the date value in your cell. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, all, who responded to my question.
Here is the working code to solve the problem:

```
function maxMinDates() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 
  var datesValues = SS.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValues();

    var datesValuesUTC = datesValues.map(row => {
      date = row[0]
      return [date.getTime()]
    })

  var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null,datesValuesUTC));
  var minDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null,datesValuesUTC));

  //Write result into cells
  SS.getSheetByName('Pivot').getRange('I11').setValue(maxDate);
  SS.getSheetByName('Pivot').getRange('I12').setValue(minDate);

}
```

It was necessary to convert the dates from the sheet range to UNIX time. The Math.max() accepts only numbers, so it worked with UNIX time format.